# Eclipse keeps crashing

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm-crash

Eclipse keeps crashing for some reason and I'm not sure why. I looked at other answers and tried to increase the heap size, but that didn't work.
These are the errors that I'm getting.

I'm on windows 8.1, java 64 bit

[image: Error code -8xxxxx]
[image: Error code 1]

Comment: I dnt think its heap size issue.

Comment: 64 bit Java running on 32 bit OS?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: You are using the Java installed in `Windows\system32`, but the Java you want to use is a 64bit one. So try the following steps (recommended anyway):

- Go to the directory where your workspace and / or Eclipse is installed.
- Create there a Shortcut, that references the file `eclipse.exe` in the Eclipse installation.
- Open that shortcut then, and add the following parameters:

  - `-vm <path>`: Absolute path to the Java runtime that should be used. Ends in (on windows) `javaw.exe`.
  - `-data <path>`: References the workspace (absolute or relative) that you were using.
- Start then Eclipse by using this shortcut, and see if that helps.

As a rule, you should use all the time Java 32bit with Eclipse 32bit and Java 64bit with Eclipse 64bit.

See the [Help Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html) for all runtime options.

Comment: It worked for longer this time, but then it crashed after a while again and I got a different error code (13) i.imgur.com/zzRUEYF.png